# How to predict actual future values using CNN and LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am using CNN + LSTM to predict stock closing stock prices of SPY. I have also tested the predictions by comparing the valid data with the predicted data, and the model works. But how do I predict actual future values.

What I want to do I just try to predict the next day's closing price.

What would I change in the code below?

```
df = web.DataReader("SPY", data_source="yahoo", start="2000-01-01", end="2022-10-19")

X = []
Y = []
window_size=100
for i in range(1 , len(df) - window_size -1 , 1):
    first = df.iloc[i,2]
    temp = []
    temp2 = []
    for j in range(window_size):
        temp.append((df.iloc[i + j, 2] - first) / first)
    temp2.append((df.iloc[i + window_size, 2] - first) / first)
    X.append(np.array(temp).reshape(100, 1))
    Y.append(np.array(temp2).reshape(1, 1))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

train_X = np.array(x_train)
test_X = np.array(x_test)
train_Y = np.array(y_train)
test_Y = np.array(y_test)

train_X = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0],1,100,1)
test_X = test_X.reshape(test_X.shape[0],1,100,1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, 100, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
# model.add(Dense(5, kernel_regularizer=L2(0.01)))

# LSTM layers
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#Final layers
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data=(test_X,test_Y), epochs=75,batch_size=40, verbose=1, shuffle =True)


# predict probabilities for test set
yhat_probs = model.predict(test_X, verbose=0)
# reduce to 1d array
yhat_probs = yhat_probs[:, 0]

predicted  = model.predict(test_X)
test_label = test_Y.reshape(-1,1)
predicted = np.array(predicted[:,0]).reshape(-1,1)
len_t = len(train_X)
for j in range(len_t , len_t + len(test_X)):
    temp = df.iloc[j,3]
    test_label[j - len_t] = test_label[j - len_t] * temp + temp
    predicted[j - len_t] = predicted[j - len_t] * temp + temp
```

Comment: Is there a problem or error with your code you're trying to fix? You predict using `model.predict()`.